# is there a way to query data based on a particular item from a json object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have user interface which looks should look like this[image]

and that picture above is just pure HTML.

So when I tried to create it with React, I am failing to align the tv shows with a particular TV channel overflowing horizontally as per the channel.

Picture of what I get in React
[image]

I am querying the data from json files that have the objects and the TV channel object looks like 
`{
        "groupID": 16481,
        "hasMediathek": true,
        "storeUrlAndroid": null,
        "storeUrlApple": null,
        "liveWeb": "https://www.zdf.de/live-tv",
        "liveApp": null,
        "defaultOrder": 1000,
        "hdp": false,
        "quality": 2,
        "name": "ZDFneo HD",
        "isEncrypted": false,
        "isHD": false,
        "dvbTriplet": "dvb://0.0.0",
        "id": null,
        "major": true
      }`

this is connected to the shows through its `groupID` which shows up as `channelID` in the shows Object. Below is a sample for the shows object

```
{
  "_id": "5b1f5c7da6cdf0cbbdb7e700",
  "showID": 892149863,
  "channelID": 16481,
  "title": "Masters of Sex",
  "subtitle": "Auf frischer Tat ertappt (Dirty Jobs)",
  "serie": {
    "no": "4",
    "title": "Auf frischer Tat ertappt",
    "seasonno": "2",
    "info": "Staffel 2 | Folge 4"
  }
```

this what I have done to query the data for channels

```js
import stations from "../data/channels.json";
import data1 from "../data/1.json";
import data2 from "../data/2.json";
import data3 from "../data/3.json";
import data4 from "../data/4.json";
import data5 from "../data/5.json";
import data6 from "../data/6.json";


class Contents extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.trans = this.trans.bind(this);
  }
  station = { ...stations };
  shows = { ...data1, ...data2, ...data3, ...data4, ...data5, ...data6 };
  trans(){
    Object.values(station.result.channels).map(value => {
      console.log(value["groupID"], "odgdggddgdd");
      return value["groupID"];
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <TopNavBar />
        <BottomNavBar />
        <div className="row">
          <section className="left-menus">
            <div className="left-items">
              {Object.values(station.result.channels).map(value => (
                <div>
                  <img
                    src={`https://cdn.hd-plus.de/senderlogos/bright-cropped/${value["groupID"]}.png`}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </section>
          
          <section className="item-center">
            
              {
                Object.values(shows.result).map(value => (
                  <div className="shows">{
                    <div className="grid-items">
                  <div className="item">
                    <small>{value.startime}</small>
                    <small>value.resolution</small>
                  </div>
                  <div className="item-name">{value.title}</div>
                  </div>
                  }
                
                </div>))}
            
          </section>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Contents;
```

I need some help with aligning the channels with their respective stations. I hope this is descriptive enough. Thank you

**Updated Code for the tiles**

```
<section className="item-center">

          {
            Object.values(station.result.channels).map(value => (

              <div className="shows">{
                shows.result.find(show => show['channelID'] === value['groupID']).map(item => (
              <div className="grid-items">
              <div className="item">
                <small>{item.startime}</small>
                <small>value.resolution</small>
              </div>
              <div className="item-name">{item.title}</div>
              </div>
                ))}

            </div>))}

      </section>
```

error message 
[image]

when I try to add Object.values() around it I get this
[image]

Comment: use a find function on your shows like this: shows.result.find(show => show.ChanneldId === value.GroupId)

Comment: Thanks a lot @GlennvanAcker, let me try it out and see

Comment: This approach keeps the application running forever.

Comment: No, that method returns a value where the conditional is true, or undefined. if it is running forever then you must be doing something wrong, it can't go in an infinite loop in any case. how are you implementing that? have you checked the console logs?

Comment: Yeah, sure it returns undefined but in real sense it shouldn't, both Id's perfectly reference each other.

Comment: In that case you must be doing something wrong, sure you didn't make any typo? can you show the updated code? and the console output?

Comment: Hey @GlennvanAcker, I have added the update take a look. I think for this filter has worked but it doesn't align the tiles with respective TV Station and some stations have shows but aren't assigned at all with filter.

For find this let me attach the error I get

Comment: That's because you are using map on a single object, map works for collections. it might be best to split off the find function, and have that return the correct html with values, or use the filter function, this way you can use the map. for the filter, just replace find with filter

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot @GlennvanAcker

Comment: Which solution did you use? i will add it as an answer below for others as well.

Comment: Hey @GlennvanAcker, I went ahead and used `shows.result.filter(show => show['channelID'] === value['groupID']).map(item => ())` . Thank you.

Comment: I added the answer below, care to mark it as solved? glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution for this (as found in the comments) is to use the filter() function. a find() function would only give back one object, or undefined, so you cannot use map on it.

```
shows.result.filter(show => show['channelID'] === value['groupID']).map(item => 
())
```

This will return every object where the channelID equals the groupID, which you can then map to a ui element.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp